# Wie man "Kastrations- und Kennzeichnungspflicht für alle Katzenhalter" klarmachen könnte

Tags: meaning

Aus der  Hohlspiegel-Kolumne im Spiegel-Magazin, die lustige oder interessante Sätze aus verschiedenen Quellen sammelt:

> Jetzt hat die Stadt Zeven reagiert und eine Kastrations- und Kennzeichnungspflicht für alle Katzenhalter verabschiedet -- mit sofortiger Wirkung.
>
> (Aus der *Zevener Zeitung*)

Ich nehme an, dass dieser Satz lustig ist, denn die Kastrations- und Kennzeichnungspflicht nicht für die Katzen, sondern für die Halter gemeint sein könnten. Wie kann man in diesem Fall den Satz klarmachen? Hier mein Versuch:

> Jetzt hat die Stadt Zeven reagiert und verabschiedet, dass **alle Katzenhalter eine Kastrations- und Kennzeichnungspflicht für ihre Katzen tragen** -- mit sofortiger Wirkung.

Comment: Wobei man sagen muss, dass das schon jeder richtig versteht und es nur lustig ist, wenn man es "lustig" nennt. Genausowie "Kinderschnitzel" oder noch besser: "Hundedecke". Da bricht man ja im Alltag auch nicht jedes mal in schallendes Gelächter aus, oder ist verwirrt. Ich glaube, ich würde einfach "für alle Katzen" sagen, doch auch da dann kann der Hohlspiegel wieder lachen. Die Leute, die das sammeln, sollten sich mal Englisch angucken. Da würden sie aus dem Lachen garnicht mehr rauskommen, soviel hängt da vom KOntext ab.

Comment: `die Pflicht der Katzenhalter zur (Sicherstellung der) Kastration und Kennzeichnung ihrer Katzen` ?

Comment: @Blutorange... kann man auch missverstehen wenn man will, indem man "Kastration" und "Kennzeichnung ihrer Katzen" als zwei Objekte für "zur" interpetiert. WEssen Kastration wäre dann offen und die sprachliche Logik würde suggerieren, dass es um der Halter Kastration geht.

Comment: Das ist wohl korrekt. Dann sollte man kuenftig wohl in diesem Stil schreiben, um die groebsten Mussverstaendnisse zu vermeiden. `((die->Pflicht)-(der)->(Katzenhalter))--zur->(((Kastration)+(und)+(Kennzeichnung))--ihrer->[<-Katzenhalter] Katzen).`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deine Annahme ist korrekt, aber man kann "tragen" nicht zusammen mit "Pflicht" verwenden. Ein passendes Verb wäre "unterliegen":

> Jetzt hat die Stadt Zeven reagiert und verabschiedet, dass alle Katzenhalter einer Kastrations- und Kennzeichnungspflicht für ihre Katzen unterliegen -- mit sofortiger Wirkung.

Wie auch @Emanuel schon vorgeschlagen hat - formal vielleicht nicht ganz korrekt, aber für jeden verständlich und unzweideutig wäre

> Jetzt hat die Stadt Zeven reagiert und eine Kastrations- und Kennzeichnungspflicht für alle Katzen verabschiedet -- mit sofortiger Wirkung.

Mit mehr Verben könnte man schreiben

> Jetzt hat die Stadt Zeven reagiert und mit sofortiger Wirkung beschlossen, dass alle Katzenhalter verpflichtet sind, ihre Tiere zu kennzeichnen und zu kastrieren.

oder noch direkter und aktiver

> Jetzt hat die Stadt Zeven reagiert und mit sofortiger Wirkung alle Katzenhalter verpflichtet, ihre Tiere zu kennzeichnen und zu kastrieren.

Ein solcher Stil ist nur (leider) im Amts- und Zeitungsdeutsch nicht sehr gebräuchlich.

Comment: Hmm... der Kennzeichnungspflicht unterliegt im normalen Sprachgebrauch allerdings der zu kennzeichnende Fakt, nicht das die Kennzeichnung vorzunehmen habende Individuum. Ausserdem kann ich den Satz jetzt auch so lesen, dass die Katzenhalter der Pflicht für ihre Katzen im Sinne von anstelle ihrer Katzen unterliegen. Wenn dann doch eher "bezüglich" oder "hinsichtlich". Der Sachverhalt ist insgesamt ein schönes Beispiel wie Nominalstil an seine Grenzen stößt. Wenn man Kontextabhängigkeit denn als solche betrachten will.

Comment: @Emanuel Der Pflicht kann doch eigentlich nur der unterliegen, der die Tätigkeit ausführen kann und muss? In [dieser Verordnung](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bartschv_2005/__12.html) wird recht klar eine Pflicht für den Tierhalter beschrieben - IMHO ist das vergleichbar. - Ansonsten hast Du aber Recht, einfach "Katzen" statt "Katzenhalter" ist zwar formal nicht ganz korrekt, ergibt aber einen einfacheren und unmißverständlichen Satz. Hatte selbst schon überlegt, ob ich das vorschlagen soll; werde es noch ergänzen.

Comment: dann guck mal nach "unterliegen der Kennzeichnungspflicht". Da kriegst du alles mögliche technische Gerät, aber kaum oder gar keine Kennzeichner.

Comment: @Emanuel Ja, der "normale Sprachgebrauch" von dem Du im ersten Kommentar geschrieben hattest (hab ich jetzt erst bemerkt) verkürzt das üblicherweise, wie auch der zweite Formulierungsvorschlag. Aber es bleibt eine Verkürzung des eigentlichen Sachverhalts: wenn ich ohne Kfz-Kennzeichen fahre, werde ich wegen einer Pflichtverletzung belangt, nicht mein Auto.

Comment: Nein :)... auch meine Version ist zweideutig. Kann auch so gelesen werden, als wäre es der Katzen Pflicht. Es ist ohne ein weiteres finites Schlicht nicht möglich, da beide, der "Verpflichtete" und das "Bepflichtete" mittels "für" angeschlossen werden.

Comment: wie wär's mit "eine Verpflichtung für alle Katzenhalter, ihre Tiere zu kennzeichnen und zu kastrieren"?

Comment: @Emanuel Auch eine gute Idee. "verpflichten" statt "eine Verpflichtung verabschieden / beschließen" gefällt mir aber noch besser.